# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: how do i resolve this?

Tags: java, command-line, runtime-error, command-line-arguments

I'm using NetBeans to write the program. The program calculates the area of a circle

The code :

```
public class Pragnya {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double PI = 3.14;
        double area = PI * r * r;
        System.out.println("Area of circle is: "+area);
    }
    
}
```

The error shown is :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Pragnya
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pragnya/Pragnya (wrong name: Pragnya)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: yes thanks but I've already done that

Comment: Can you share more details, like the namespace and the exact name of your file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this within netbeans, this error can't/shouldn't occur (then you did quite a number on how you managed to misconfigure this project!). If you're running it from the command line:

```
cd ..
java pragnya.Pragnya
```

Alternatively, assuming JDK11+, you can just run `java Pragnya.java` (not javac, then java - just `java` the source file).

Read up on packages and classpath structure if you want to know why you need to it this way.

Comment: Thank you                                                                                                                                                 Now it shows                                                                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at pragnya.Pragnya.main(Pragnya.java:15) i.e after compiling using java Pragnya.java because i have version 15 of JDK

Comment: `int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` because you don have parsed an command line argument?

Comment: Thanks but in cmd i pass an argument i.e java Pragnya 3 and it shows that error

Comment: No, it won't. You're passing it wrong, then.